# Does iFrame have any events suitable for when a JavaScript & HTML page are embedded in modal(Bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, iframe, modal-dialog, chart.js

hi i am developing a Boostrap application.
I wanted to show a modal form that loads a separate page via iframe tags.
modal html that loads iframe in addition to title and body looks like this

modal html looks like this

```
    <!-- the modal form is described on the following HTML -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>One fine body…</p>
          </div>
            <iframe src="path/radar.html"></iframe>

          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

          </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
      </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

This works!verified.

but the html i wan to load has javascript that runs on window.onload
there it runs a couple of lines to draw a chart using chart.js
here is the script:

```
    <script>
    var radarChartData = {
    labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running"],
    datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
    },{
    label: "My Second dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]}]};
    window.onload = function(){
    window.myRadar = new    Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData,{responsive: true});}
    </script>
```

is there any way(ie an event&placehlder for iframe) to run the two lines of code when the modal is shown via a button rather relative to a window?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it, hope you have embedded jQuery library, as you're using bootstrap you should include jQuery script library in the page(using jQuery is more standardized and best approach).

Let us say you're opening the model from button with id="btnShowModal", using jQuery you can run the function upon clicking of the button as below:

```
$("#btnShowModal").click(function(){
   //here you can add the code what ever you want to execute on button  
   window.myRadar = new   Chart(document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d")).Radar(radarChartData,{responsive: true});
});
```